# Linux webcam software

Tags: software-rec, camera

What are some good full-featured (whatever that means) webcam applications in linux. I know about cheese, but found some of its features lacking. Are there any others?

Comment: which features do you want?

Comment: @pootzko: I guess that's the thing, I've never really used webcam software before (even on windows) so I'm not sure what's there

Comment: well, you have to ask more precisely. otherwise how do you expect people to help you if you don't know what you want? you didn't formulate your question right then this one is too subjective...

Comment: `whatever that means` ? be precise.

Answer (score 2):

- [ZoneMinder](http://www.zoneminder.com/)
- [Motion](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/WebHome)
- [ekiga](http://www.ekiga.org/)
- [peercast](http://www.peercast.org/) + [geekcast](http://home.gna.org/geekast/)
- or even [hascii](http://ascii.dyne.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Try `guvcview`, which is available in Ubuntu